# Why does this Swift code snippet compile? How does it work?

Tags: xcode, swift

Today, I saw some sample Swift 2.0 (Xcode 7.2) code that can be summarised as:

```
let colours = ["red", "green", "blue"]
let r1 = colours.contains("The red one.".containsString)  // true
let y1 = colours.contains("The yellow one.".containsString)  // false
```

I would have expected a compilation error due to the lack of parenthesis on the `containsString()` function.  In fact, I'm not even sure how the recursion is working.  Are the Strings recursing through each item in the `colours` array or vice versa?

Any explanation appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are actually doing is calling the method `.contains(predicate: String -> Bool)` (the actual method can throw, but that's not relevant here)

This means that you are asking the array `colours` if it contains an element that conforms to that predicate, which is `"The red one.".containsString`. So the array is checking its elements one by one and checking it against that predicate. If it finds one, it will return true, otherwise it will return false.

The code above does this:

```
"The red one.".containsString("red")
"The red one.".containsString("green")
"The red one.".containsString("blue")

"The yellow one.".containsString("red")
"The yellow one.".containsString("green")
"The yellow one.".containsString("blue")
```

And it checks if it got `true` somewhere.

Comment: A cool remark: I was thinking in C, which would do a totally different thing, it would check if an array of strings contained a function, and the compiler would tell you it will return false every time.

Comment: Two good answers (and a bit of reading over the weekend) have helped me to understand whats going on.  I hadn't noticed that the Array.contains function was overloaded:

Comment: ...nor the relationship between functions and closures (and the real implications of having functions as "first class citizens" in a language).  Finally, functional programming becomes a little clearer.

Ideally, I'd credit both answers but I'm plumping for @vrwin (only because he has a lower rep. score).  Thanks both.

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan Thanks for helping out a fellow programmer! :)

Answer (score 5):

In Swift, functions can be considered as named closures. Quoting from [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) on closures:

> Global and nested functions, as introduced in Functions, are actually special cases of closures

However `containsString()` is an instance method (thanks Martin R for your observation). The code works, because [instance methods in Swift are actually curried functions](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/), which fall into the named closure category.

What happens is that `"The red one.".containsString` gets translated to a global function like this:

```
String.containsString("The red one.")
```

which returns a function `(String) -> Bool`, that ends up being called by `contains` like this:

```
String.containsString("The red one.")("red")
String.containsString("The red one.")("green")
String.containsString("The red one.")("blue")
```

Now, considering the signature of `contains`:

```
public func contains(@noescape predicate: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool
```

and signature of `containsString`:

```
public func containsString(other: String) -> Bool
```

we can see that on an array of strings the `predicate` parameter and the result of `String.containsString("The red one.")` are compatible: both expect a `String` as argument and return a `Bool`. So the compiler can happily call the curried function.

Comment: Much of your answer looks good to me. But `containsString()` is an instance method, not a global or nested function.

Comment: You have a point... I researched a little bit more and found the explanation of why instance functions work. Thanks @MartinR for the feedback

Comment: Shouldn't `String.containsString("The red one.")` return a function with a `(String) -> Bool` signature, instead of `(String) -> String` as the signature of `containsString` is `public func containsString(other: String) -> Bool`?

Comment: @MarcoBoschi you're right, thanks for noticing the typo, will correct the answer.